# Unable to determine server PID. in ambari

Tags: ubuntu, ambari

Hi I am a debutant in ambari and I have this problem of server PID:

I am trying to install Ambari 2.5.2.0 following the steps indicated in 
https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.5.2.0/bk_ambari-installation/content/ch_Getting_Ready.html

I use Ubuntu 14 and my Internet access is through a proxy.

I have tried the following two configurations: 1.embedded PostgreSQL, and 2. a standalone PostgreSQL. In both cases, I have the same error when I start Ambari server. The error message displayed on the screen is the following:

```
Server PID at: /var/run/ambari-server/ambari-server.pid Server out at: /var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.out Server log at: /var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.log Waiting for server start.........Unable to determine server PID. Retrying... ......Unable to determine server PID. Retrying... ......Unable to determine server PID. Retrying... 
ERROR: Exiting with exit code -1. REASON: Ambari Server java process died with exitcode 1. Check /var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.out for more information.
```

Please, do you have any idea of the origin of the problem?

The content of ambari-server.out file is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Ambari from binary packages, or from source? com.google.inject.CreationException means that Dependency Injection configuration is broken, and usually points to a broken source code